# What's wrong with this code? SimpleXMLElement

Tags: simplexml, php

```
$fn = $Cache_Path . '/n' . $Node . '.xml';
$store = file_get_contents( $fn );
SimpleXMLElement;
$xml = new ( $store );
$link = '';
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in.....

Comment: In what? You left out only the essential part...

Comment: full code http://paste.ee/p/LtlQU Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in...... index.php on line 567

Comment: You should edit that comment in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
$fn = $Cache_Path . '/n' . $Node . '.xml';
$store = file_get_contents( $fn );
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement ( $store );
$link = '';
```